# Trigger asp.net event from html controls added by jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

In my WebApplication I have some code like this.

```
$('.form-content').append('<ul>' + 
    '<li runat="server" OnClick="SelectUser" value="1">User 1</li>' +
    '<li runat="server" OnClick="SelectUser" value="2">User 2</li>' +
    '<li runat="server" OnClick="SelectUser" value="3">User 3</li>' +
'</ul>');
```

But, when I select the list item, the Event doesn't trigger. 
Is there any way to bind ASP.NET event to html control which is dynamically generated by JQuery/Javascript ?

I tried using WebMethod. But, It cannot update the ASP.Net controls since the method is static.

Comment: You can try with `WebMethod` and call that `WebMethod` from `$.ajax` and obviously that `$.ajax` can be called for any HTML control.. :)

Comment: Tell me one thing! `SelectUser` is a method on serverside??

Comment: Yes... Its a server method. 
WebMethod doesn't help me, as I have lot of textboxes and gridviews to be filled by this function. I cannot set one by one by JQuery AJAX post result. WebMethod on the same page doesn't allow me to directly access the controls;

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you can try this, add hidden `asp:button` on your page and make sure that you have an onclick event attached to it.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelectUser" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="btnSelectUser_OnClick" />
```

then in your javascript add click events to your `li`

```
$("li").click(function() {    
   $("#btnSelectUser").trigger("click")
});
```

that should fire the serverside event.

The other thing that you will need to keep in mind is that you will need to place hidden `labels` on the page to save the selected values of the `li`

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $("#hiddenLabel").val("Get value from attr")
    $("#btnSelectUser").trigger("click")
});
```

then those values should also be available on the server.

**This is by now means the best why to-do it, but it will work.**

Comment: Hi, Its working... Still I am searching for a better solution. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hws4293/6/) similar to your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
        debugger
        addList();
        return false;
    });

    function addList() {
        $('.form-content').append('<ul>' +
            '<li runat="server"  value="1">User 1</li>' +
            '<li runat="server"  value="2">User 2</li>' +
            '<li runat="server"  value="3">User 3</li>' +

            '</ul>');
    }
    $(".form-content").on("click", "li", function () {
        SelectUser($(this));
    });



function SelectUser(obj) {
    alert("User Selected!");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./YourPage.aspx/SelectUser",
        data: ("ID=" + $(obj).prop("id")),
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
});
```

You can do anything inside `SelectUser()`. Even Invoke the `Serverside event`.

Comment: You can call the `SelectUser` of server side from ajax. I have updated the code.

Comment: Yes. Its possible with an ASP.NET WebMethod. 
But the problem here is: Since WebMethod is static, It cannot access any of the controls on my page. Hence; It's useless...
If I use  ajax result to populate the data, Its a heavy task for me.